# QTableView with multiline cell

Tags: c++, qt, desktop-application, qt5, qtableview

How can I create a QTableView multiline cell?

I'm filling the table using the code bellow.
But Whem `GetDescription()` returns a long string, the content is terminated with `...`

There is some way to automatic break the line?

```
QStandardItemModel * model = new QStandardItemModel(logos.size(), 2, this);
model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, new QStandardItem(QString("")));
model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, new QStandardItem(QString("Nome")));
model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, new QStandardItem(QString("Descrição")));

int row = 0;
foreach(Item * item, items)
{
    QStandardItem* check = new QStandardItem(true);
    check->setCheckable(true);
    model->setItem(row, 0, check);

    QStandardItem *nameItem = new QStandardItem(QString(item->GetName()));
    nameItem->setEditable(false);
    model->setItem(row, 1, nameItem);

    QStandardItem *descriptionItem = new QStandardItem(item->GetDescription());
    descriptionItem->setEditable(false);
    descriptionItem->setToolTip(logo->GetDescription());
    model->setItem(row, 2, descriptionItem);
    row++;
}

ui->tableView->setModel(model);
ui->tableView->resizeColumnToContents(0);
ui->tableView->resizeColumnToContents(1);
ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView::Fixed);
ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView::Fixed);
ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(2, QHeaderView::Stretch);
ui->tableView->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I only add to my code:

```
ui->tableView->verticalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
```

Answer (score 11):

I think word wrapping is what you're looking for. Make sure that you've [enabled wordwrap](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtableview.html#wordWrap-prop) for the QTableView, then [manually resize the rows to fit their contents](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtableview.html#resizeRowsToContents). That will replace the ellipse with the text.

As you mentioned in your answer, you can [set the QHeaderView to resize](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#setResizeMode) to contents [automatically](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#ResizeMode-enum), but if you do a lot of adding and removing this will slow things down. I prefer to manually resize with a large addition/subtraction, particularly since the user might find it annoying to be unable to resize it themselves.

Here's some example code that enables word wrap, sets the ellipse to appear in the middle (my preference), and then *manually* resizes the row height to fit the contents at word boundaries:

```
ui->tableView->setWordWrap(true);
ui->tableView->setTextElideMode(Qt::ElideMiddle);
ui->tableView->resizeRowsToContents();
```

Comment: You may also consider changing the QTableView's [elide mode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#TextElideMode-enum).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the only way to implement multiline text drawing in cells is implementing own delegate.

You can derive from [`QItemDelegate`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qitemdelegate.html).

You'll have to

- implement own `sizeHint` function, based on `QFontMetrics`
- and override `drawDisplay` function to actually display text. You can use [`QPainter::drawText`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qpainter.html#drawText-4) to display multiline text. So, you don't have to care about drawing focus and selection rectangles and own painting function will be simple.

Comment: How can I subclass `QItemDelegate`? How can I set the new class in `QTableView`?

Comment: What do you mean by 'How can I subclass QItemDelegate'? Just subclass. You can set your delegate with `QAbstractItemView::setItemDelegate` function.

Comment: How is that the only way? You can enable wordwrap via the QTableView.

Answer (score 0):

```
tableView->resizeRowsToContents();
```

Comment: As it stands, your answer is rather.. short. Could you perhaps expand on it to clarify how it differs from other answers and what its advantages are?

Comment: If solves your problem, the advantage is simplicity. Comment that this only resizes the heights rows when does the call. If the user resizes the table, the rows widths are resized, but the heights remains the same. If the text doesn't enter in the new row size, appears ...